# Error inflating ListFragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

My app is crashing as soon as it starts. Im getting the following error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class
```

I've looked at several other similar questions but none of the solutions work for me.  Why is this happening? Line #34 in the error refers to the

```
<fragment>..</fragment>
```

in mainActivity.xml

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




}

public void FragmentOneClick(View v)
{
    ListFragment myFragment=new fragmentOne();
    FragmentManager fm= getSupportFragmentManager();//getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_switch,   myFragment );
    ft.commit();

}

public void FragmentTwoClick(View v)
{
    Fragment myFragment=new fragmentTwo();
    FragmentManager fm= getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_switch,  myFragment);
    ft.commit();

}

}
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.nirvan.fragment_example.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:onClick="FragmentOneClick"
    android:text="Fragment1"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
    >
    </Button>

<Button
    android:text="Fragment2"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="FragmentTwoClick"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fragment_switch"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fragment_switch">
    android:layout_weight="2"
</Button>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_switch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:name="com.example.nirvan.fragment_example.fragmentOne"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment_one" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**FragmentOne.java**

```
//import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
//import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;

public class fragmentOne extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment
{
String dates[]={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView;
    rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);



    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,dates);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

**FragmentTwo.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class fragmentTwo extends Fragment
{



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_two, container, false);
}


}
```

**FragmentOne.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.nirvan.fragment_example.fragmentOne">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />


</FrameLayout>
```

**fragmentTwo.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.nirvan.fragment_example.fragmentTwo"
android:background="#548f47">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="fragment 2" />






</FrameLayout>
```

**Log**

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                            Process: com.example.nirvan.fragment_example, PID: 26870
                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nirvan.fragment_example/com.example.nirvan.fragment_example.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                     at com.example.nirvan.fragment_example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
                                                                                     at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:402)
```

Comment: Edit your post and include the complete stack trace of the exception. Also, please don't include all of your code. The exception stack trace should he;p narrow down which code snippets are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your FragmentOne.xml with this

```
 <FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

   <ListView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="left|top" />


</FrameLayout>
```

Here you just needed to change the id of ListView to this

```
 android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Can you explain why changing the code for ID works?

Comment: Because you have extended ListFragment in FragmentOne so it internally needs this @android:id/list